# Checkbox treeview functionality is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, treeview

This is below code is not working as expected. I mean, on this treeview, when I press the last 4 checkboxs, then, the first checkbox should be checked automatically. Whenever the sublevel checkbox['checkboxG2'] count comes to 4, then, the first level['checkboxG1'] should be selected automatically. Any help please?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="BuCheck" class="BusinessCont">
<p><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG1" id="checkbox1" class="form-checkbox" value="Trauva"/><label for="checkbox1" class="form-label">Trauva</label></p>
    <p>&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG2" id="checkbox2" class="form-checkbox" value="Nitro"/><label for="checkbox2" class="form-label">Nitro</label></p>
    <p>&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG2" id="checkbox3" class="form-checkbox" value="Global Market"/><label for="checkbox3" class="form-label">Global Market</label></p>
    <p>&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG2" id="checkbox4" class="form-checkbox" value="Government Services"/><label for="checkbox4" class="form-label">Government Services</label></p>
    <p>&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG2" id="checkbox5" class="form-checkbox" value="PHASIZE"/><label for="checkbox5" class="form-label">PHASIZE</label></p>
    </div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var checkBoxBusiness = function(){
console.log("Checkbox button clickes");
var myChekall = $("#BuCheck input[name=checkboxG2]"), myChecksin = $("#BuCheck input[name=checkboxG1]")[0], myCheckedAll=$("#BuCheck input[name=checkboxG2]:checked");
console.log(myCheckedAll.length);
if(myChekall.length == myCheckedAll.length) {
$(myChecksin).attr("checked", "true");
}
}
checkBoxBusiness();
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what I understand is that you have 5 check boxes. Can you elaborate on the condition on what should get checked on click of what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this part

```
checkBoxBusiness();
```

to

```
$("#BuCheck input[name=checkboxG2]").on('change', checkBoxBusiness);
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hft3Lf8b/1/).

EDIT:

I've been modified my code. Now it can uncheck main checkbox when all sublevel checkboxes are unchecked:

```
 var checkBoxBusiness = function(){
    console.log("Checkbox button clickes");
    var myChekall = $("#BuCheck input[name=checkboxG2]"), 
        myChecksin = $("#BuCheck input[name=checkboxG1]"), 
        myCheckedAll=$("#BuCheck input[name=checkboxG2]:checked");
    console.log(myCheckedAll.length);

    if(myChekall.length == myCheckedAll.length) {
        myChecksin.prop('checked', true);
    } else if(!myCheckedAll.length) {
        myChecksin.prop('checked', false);
    }
}
$("#BuCheck input[name=checkboxG2]").on('change', checkBoxBusiness);
```

New [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/argxsvws/1/).

Comment: Hi, Could you please make this also works when uncheck all the sublevel checkbox?  I mean, when i uncheck all the checkboxe, then, the first level checkbox[checkboxG1] automatically be unchecked. any help?

Comment: Hi, @User123. I did what you need. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want another option here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[name='checkboxG2']").on("click", function () {
        if ($("[name='checkboxG2']:checked").length == 4) {
            $("[name='checkboxG1']").prop('checked', true);
        }
    })
})
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/af8h9e6r/1/

Comment: Danilo: I think, your code will make `Poor DOM manipulation`, Could you make this speed performance?. I like your simplicity of code, Pls Correct me if my thought is wrong.

Comment: Could you please elaborate about why you see poor DOM manipulation here?

Comment: I do not understand your question exactly, but, the above will look through all the elements inside DOM in body. Whenever, it gets its relevant element, only then, It will do the action that you mentioned, So, each time when you click the checkbox, it look through all the elements again and again. It makes DOM manipulation slow. Am i making sense?

Comment: I slightly updated the code to show what happens. When the DOM is ready (basically when the page has been loaded), the code uses a jQuery selector to find all DOM elements having the property name='checkboxG2'. For each of the found elements, an event handler function is attached to the "click" event: basically the function is executed whenever a click occurs on one of the elements that matched the selector. Only when this event occurs the function is executed, the IF-clause is checked and if necessary the property "checked" is set for elements matching the selector [name='checkboxG1'].